# Accessing std::vector data members of a class from its member functions

Tags: c++

I have a class which defines the following members in a header file (.hpp):

```
public :
  int loadData(char* filename);

private :
  std::vector<vertex> vertices;
  std::vector<triangle> triangles;
  std::vector<frame> frames;
```

The `vertex`, `triangle` and `frame` are structures defined in another header file included in this header file.

Now, in the definition of the function `loadData` in the .cpp, I cannot access the members `vertices`, `triangles` and `frames`. For example, I have the following code resulting in the error shown under it:

```
cout << "total vertices stored= " << vertices.size() << endl;

motionViewer.cpp:59: error: 'vertices' was not declared in this scope
```

Why cannot I access these members?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Post the full function, at a guess, I'd say you were missing the class qualification for the definition of that function (e.g, if your class is `foo`, when you define the function in the cpp file, it should be `foo::loadData`)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire function

Comment: As embarrassing an error that was, that was that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blind shot: because you forget to put the class-name before the loadData-method in your .cpp:

```
int className::loadData(char* filename)
```

But to be sure you need to show more code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you forgot to use the (class) scope in the cpp file.

Like:

```
void motionViewer::loadData(char* filename)
{
    // ...
}
```

Assuming the name of the class is `motionViewer`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you haven't missed the `::`? In the cpp:

```
#include "header_name.h"

ClassName::loadData( ..
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. do your define your structures in another namespace?
2. have you missed the class scope for the definition of the function?
3. have you correctly defined your structures (like not missing the tail semicolon) ?